# How to filter Mongoose Schemas that has a `null` value in one of its items inside?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am fairly new to Coding and JavaScript altogether. I am trying to render the Data inside stored inside my MongoDB in my EJS template. 
The specific code is here in `app.js`

```
// Individual Customer's page
app.get("/customers/all-customers/:customerPhoneNumber", function (req, res) {
  const requestedCustomerPhoneNumber = req.params.customerPhoneNumber;
  Customer.findOne({ phone: requestedCustomerPhoneNumber }, function (
    err,
    foundCustomer
  ) {
    Purchase.find({ customerPhone: requestedCustomerPhoneNumber }, function (
      err,
      foundPurchases
    ) {
      // console.log(foundPurchases);

      foundPurchases.forEach(function (purchase) {
        const planPurchaseID = purchase.purchaseID;
        CompletedSession.findOne({ planPurchaseID: planPurchaseID }, function (err, foundSession) {
          res.render("customer-page", {
            customerPurchases: foundPurchases,
            pageTitle: foundCustomer.name,
            customerID: foundCustomer._id,
            customerPhone: foundCustomer.phone,
            customerWhatsapp: foundCustomer.whatsappNumber,
            customerEmail: foundCustomer.email,
            customerDOB: foundCustomer.dob,
            customerGender: foundCustomer.gender,
            customerRegDate: foundCustomer.registrationDate,
            comletedSessions: foundSession.sessions,
          });
        })
      })
    });
  });
});
```

In this code, Some of the document has `null` value of `sessions` in `foundSession`, which cause my program to crash when I try to render the array with `forEach()` loop. 
Is there any way to automatically drop `foundSession` with `null` value of `sessions` so that I can only pass the `foundSession` that has no `null` value of `sessions` and prevent my program from crashing?

Comment: your foreach wont work anyway because it will iterate only 1x and response the first result.

Comment: So How could I have resolve this? Presently I am getting Type Error when I try to render the `completedSessions` array in ejs as I have two documents, one with a `null` value

Comment: @raymond-redd : Are you sure your issue is with `sessions` being `null` in DB doc ? So everywhere you do `.find` or `.findOne()` do this `.find({...}).lean(true).exec(callback func)` Also in `CompletedSession.findOne({ planPurchaseID: planPurchaseID , sessions: { $ne: null} }).lean(true).exec(callback func)`, try it..